# How to adjust a header component's height automatically based on which device the app is running on in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

A header component in my app is just a simple `UIView` with a title and a bottom border and the height of it is 64, it looks like this on any other devices except for iPhone X:

[image]

However, on an iPhone X device, it looks like this:

[image]

How do I automatically make the height of the header larger when the app is running on an iPhone X device but remain 64 on any other devices like this?

[image]

Comment: Why arę you using a custom view for this and not 'UINavigationController' configured to look like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points to help you get into the right direction:

#### Do you have a solid reason NOT to use a `UINavigationController?`

This would give you a navigation bar + navigation title for free without having to care about it.

#### If so, use Safe Layout Guide

With the arrival of the iPhone X, apple introduced the concept of "Safe Area". For every iPhone except the iPhone X, it returns the top-most view bounds, but for the iPhone X it returns a rectangle that stops at the rounded corners.

In order to fix your issue, you should constraint your view's top to the top of the safe area, instead of the top layout guide.

Comment: I actually don't have a reason not to use `UINavigationController`, reading it now, thank you very much!